# How to do a camel case to sentence case in dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Something is wrong with my attempt:

```
String camelToSentence(String text) {
  var result = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'/([A-Z])/g'), r" $1");
  var finalResult = result[0].toUpperCase() + result.substring(1);
  return finalResult;
}

void main(){
  print(camelToSentence("camelToSentence"));
}
```

It just prints "CamelToSentence" instead of "Camel To Sentence".

Looks like the problem is here `r" $1";` but I don't know why.

Comment: What should the method return?

Comment: Camel To Sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `/` and `/g` in the pattern.

About the The [replaceAll](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method:

> Notice that the replace string is not interpreted. If the replacement
> depends on the match (for example on a RegExp's capture groups), use
> the replaceAllMapped method instead.

As is does not match, `result[0]` returns *c* and `result.substring(1)` contains *amelToSentence* so you are concatenating an uppercased c with amelToSentence giving *CamelToSentence*

You can also use lookarounds

```
(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])
```

- `(?<!^)` Assert not the start of the string
- `(?=[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char A-Z to the right

[Dart demo](https://ideone.com/3AxzUP)

For example

```
String camelToSentence(String text) {
  var result = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])'), r" ");
  var finalResult = result[0].toUpperCase() + result.substring(1);
  return finalResult;
}
 
void main() {
    print(camelToSentence("camelToSentence"));
}
```

Output

```
Camel To Sentence
```

Comment: for flutter web, lookbehind is not supported on Safari, so, this solution, although it works perfectly fine everywhere else, just keep in mind if you're targeting web, safari will give you an error

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```dart
String camelToSentence(String text) {
  return text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^([a-z])|[A-Z]'), 
          (Match m) => m[1] == null ? " ${m[0]}" : m[1].toUpperCase());
}
```

Here,

- `^([a-z])|[A-Z]` - matches and captures into Group 1 a lowercase ASCII letter at the start of string, or just matches an uppercase letter anywhere in the string
- `(Match m) => m[1] == null ? " ${m[0]}" : m[1].toUpperCase()` returns as the replacement the uppercases Group 1 value (if it was matched) or a space + the matched value otherwise.